"the granting" vs "granting"

Hi, I can't see why we put a "the" here. It is not talking about a specific citizenship, it's just giving general information.

The distinction is not clear-cut in that sentence and either way would be grammatical.

I'm sure this is a duplicate although it's not easy to search for, but anyway. "Granting citizenship" would be fine in other contexts (e.g. if anyone could grant citizenship in many ways), but "the granting of citizenship" emphasises that it's a particular procedure with particular rules.

Your question is this:

__________ of citizenship usually requires a period of legal residence, together with other factors (for example, language proficiency).
A) To grant
B) Granting
C) Having granted
D) The granting
E) To be granted

(D) The granting is the correct choice, and it all hinges on the word of. The words "of citizenship" will require an article because it makes the item specific.

The granting of citizenship usually requires...

It's not citizenship that's referred to, it's the granting. So it's a specific granting -- the granting of citizenship. Here are some other examples:

The Dukes of Hazzard
The residents of Boston
The President of the United States

If you remove the word of, then (B) would be the best answer:

Granting citizenship usually requires a period of legal residence...

Now you're referring to citizenship, and it's general citizenship, so you don't use an article.

"The granting citizenship" is ungrammatical but "granting citizenship" is not ungrammatical. Nor is "granting of citizenship" especially in a sentence where the word "usually" or "generally" occurs.
